# Reduction of a Jacobi-type continued fraction

Tags: special-functions, continued-fractions

I am trying to reduce the following Jacobi-like continued fraction(or J-fraction):

$$f(z)=z+K_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{R_{n}k^2}{z+Q_{n}}$$

where,
$$R_{n}=n\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right),\; Q_n=n\left(n+m+\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

where $k \in \mathbb{R},m \in \mathbb{Z}$ are constants

But, it seems like this one might not be expressible in terms of elementary functions. Can one express it terms of finite compositions of elementary functions/elliptic functions/Heun function?

Note that I am aware of the fact that this sum may not always converge(depending on the values of $m$ and $z$). Even so, I want to express $f(z)$ in a form that isolates the $z$ dependence from the possibly divergent piece.

Comment: Did you try Gauss continued fraction https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_continued_fraction ?

Comment: @Nemo It doesn't work as the form of the partial denominator there is $1+Q_n*z$ and not the one I have.

Comment: @Nemo Is there a generalization of Gauss continued fraction to include analytic Heun functions?